Snowflake - Procedure is created but fails when executed
I have a stored procedure that is pretty long but the next one i think reflects what it does:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE db.schema.sp_1(
    param_col_1 VARCHAR,
    param_col_2 VARCHAR,
    param_col_3 VARCHAR,
    param_col_7 VARCHAR,
    param_col_8 VARCHAR,
    param_col_9 VARCHAR,
    param_col_10 VARCHAR,
    param_col_11 INTEGER,
    param_col_12 INTEGER,
    param_json_info_1 VARCHAR,
    param_json_info_2 VARCHAR,
    param_json_info_3 VARCHAR,
    param_json_info_4 VARCHAR)
RETURNS TABLE(
    column1 VARCHAR(16777216),
    column2 DATE,
    column3 VARCHAR(16777216),
    column4 VARCHAR(16777216),
    column5 DATE,
    column6 DATE,
    column7 VARCHAR(16777216),
    column8 VARCHAR(16777216),
    column9 VARCHAR(16777216),
    column10 FLOAT,
    column11 FLOAT,
    column12 FLOAT)
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
$$
DECLARE
    res RESULTSET;
    query VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    query := 'WITH staging_1 AS (SELECT col0, col1 ,col2 ,col3 ,(col4 = "P") AS col4, col5, col6 FROM db.schema.table_1 WHERE col1 = "' || param_col_1 || '" AND col2 = "' || param_col_2 || '"::DATE AND iff("' || param_col_3 || '" IS NOT NULL, col3 = "' || param_col_3 || '", true)), staging_2 AS (SELECT stg1.col1 ,stg1.col2, stg1.col3, stg1.col4, stg1.col5, stg1.col6, stg2.col7, stg2.col8, stg2.col9, stg2.col10, stg2.col11, stg2.col12, stg2.col13, stg2.col14, stg2.col15, stg2.col16, stg2.col17, stg.col18 FROM staging_1 stg1 LEFT JOIN db.schema.table_2 stg2 ON stg1.col0 = stg2.col0 WHERE iff("' || param_col_7 || '" IS NOT NULL, stg2.col7 = "' || param_col_7 || '", true) AND iff("' || param_col_8 || '" IS NOT NULL, stg2.col8 = "' || param_col_8 || '", true), last_filter AS (SELECT stg2.col1 ,stg2.col2, stg2.col3, stg2.col4, stg2.col5, stg2.col6, stg2.col7, stg2.col8, stg2.col9, stg2.col10, stg2.col11, stg2.col12, CASE  WHEN "' || param_col_9 || '" = "DATE" AND "' || param_col_10 || '" = "DESC" THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stg2.col5 DESC, COALESCE(TIME(stg2.col5), TIME("00:00")) DESC) WHEN "' || param_col_9 || '" = "DATE" AND "' || param_col_10 || '" = "ASC" THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stg2.col5 ASC, COALESCE(TIME(stg2.col5), TIME("00:00")) ASC) WHEN "' || param_col_9 || '" = "AMOUNT" AND "' || param_col_10 || '" = "DESC" THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stg2.col10 DESC) WHEN "' || param_col_9 || '" = "AMOUNT" AND "' || param_col_10 || '" = "ASC" THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stg2.col10 ASC) END row_num FROM staging_2 stg2 INNER JOIN (SELECT  DISTINCT VALUE:account::INT account,  VALUE:bankCode::VARCHAR bankCode,  VALUE:currency::VARCHAR currency FROM (SELECT  parse_json('' || param_json_info_1 || '') as src) src, lateral flatten(input => src) ) cts ON stg2.col13 = cts.account AND stg2.col14 = cts.bankCode AND stg2.col15 = cts.currency WHERE 1 = 1 and iff('' || param_json_info_2 || '' is not null, stg2.col16 in ( select VALUE:transactionType::INT from (  select parse_json('' || param_json_info_2 || '') as src ) src, lateral flatten(input => src) where value is not null ) , true) and iff('' || param_json_info_3 || '' is not null, stg2.col17 in ( select VALUE:storeCode::VARCHAR from ( select parse_json('' || param_json_info_3 || '') as src ) src, lateral flatten(input => src) where value is not null) , true) and stg2.col18 in ( select VALUE:paymentMethod::VARCHAR from ( select parse_json('' || param_json_info_4 || '') as src ) src, lateral flatten(input => src) where value is not null) QUALIFY row_num BETWEEN ' || param_col_11 || '::NUMBER(38,0) + 1 AND ' || param_col_11 || '::NUMBER(38,0) + ' || param_col_12 || '::NUMBER(38,0)) SELECT  col1 column1, col2 column2, col3 column3, col4 column4, col5 column5, col6 column6, col7 column7, col8 column8, col9 column9, col10 column10, col11 column11, col12 column12 FROM last_filter';
    res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
    RETURN TABLE(res);
END;
$$;

I'm calling this procedure with the next statement:
call db.schema.sp_1('XXXXXXXX','2024-05-06', null, null, null, 'DATE', 'DESC', 0, 200, '{"data":{"account":"11111111","bankCode":"99","currency":"840"}}', '{"data":{"transactionType":"100"}}', null, '{"data":{"paymentMethod":"C"}}');

But getting errors like this:
Error:'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 7 at position 10 : SQL compilation error: (line 99)
parse error line 1 at position 11,021 near ''.
syntax error line 1 at position 10,191 unexpected 'AS'. (line 99)
Of course this error means nothing if i don't put the actual script but, i follow all the things that i have currently in the final version of the sp (this one is created without errors).
Thanks

Try removing the AS before col4

i removed all the AS in the renaming columns, and now alleging on: {   "Error type": "STATEMENT_ERROR",   "SQLCODE": 1003,   "SQLERRM": "SQL compilation error:\nparse error line 1 at position 10,862 near ''.",   "SQLSTATE": "42000" }

As there's obviously a typo somewhere in your code, the only way anyone is going to be able to help you is if you show the actual code (or a cut-down version of it that still shows this error). The error message seems to suggest that all your code is on a single line - which makes it difficult to narrow down where the issue is from the error message. Has your code not got carriage returns at the end of each line - possibly just a newline character?

Looks like some of your parameters are Null, which is making the string "query" = Null, try executing the following procedure and you will see that your SQL that you are executing is null.
call sp_1('XXXXXXXX','2024-05-06', null, null, null, 'DATE', 'DESC', 0, 200, '{"data":{"account":"11111111","bankCode":"99","currency":"840"}}', '{"data":{"transactionType":"100"}}', null, '{"data":{"paymentMethod":"C"}}');


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_1(
    param_col_1 VARCHAR,
    param_col_2 VARCHAR,
    param_col_3 VARCHAR,
    param_col_7 VARCHAR,
    param_col_8 VARCHAR,
    param_col_9 VARCHAR,
    param_col_10 VARCHAR,
    param_col_11 INTEGER,
    param_col_12 INTEGER,
    param_json_info_1 VARCHAR,
    param_json_info_2 VARCHAR,
    param_json_info_3 VARCHAR,
    param_json_info_4 VARCHAR)
returns varchar(200)
LANGUAGE SQL 
AS
$$
DECLARE
    res RESULTSET;
    query VARCHAR;
    err  varchar;
BEGIN
    query := 'WITH staging_1 AS (SELECT col0, col1 ,col2 ,col3 ,(col4 = "P") AS col4, col5, col6 FROM db.schema.table_1 WHERE col1 = "' || param_col_1 || '" AND col2 = "' || param_col_2 || '"::DATE AND iff("' || param_col_3 || '" IS NOT NULL, col3 = "' || param_col_3 || '", true)), staging_2 AS (SELECT stg1.col1 ,stg1.col2, stg1.col3, stg1.col4, stg1.col5, stg1.col6, stg2.col7, stg2.col8, stg2.col9, stg2.col10, stg2.col11, stg2.col12, stg2.col13, stg2.col14, stg2.col15, stg2.col16, stg2.col17, stg.col18 FROM staging_1 stg1 LEFT JOIN db.schema.table_2 stg2 ON stg1.col0 = stg2.col0 WHERE iff("' || param_col_7 || '" IS NOT NULL, stg2.col7 = "' || param_col_7 || '", true) AND iff("' || param_col_8 || '" IS NOT NULL, stg2.col8 = "' || param_col_8 || '", true), last_filter AS (SELECT stg2.col1 ,stg2.col2, stg2.col3, stg2.col4, stg2.col5, stg2.col6, stg2.col7, stg2.col8, stg2.col9, stg2.col10, stg2.col11, stg2.col12, CASE  WHEN "' || param_col_9 || '" = "DATE" AND "' || param_col_10 || '" = "DESC" THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stg2.col5 DESC, COALESCE(TIME(stg2.col5), TIME("00:00")) DESC) WHEN "' || param_col_9 || '" = "DATE" AND "' || param_col_10 || '" = "ASC" THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stg2.col5 ASC, COALESCE(TIME(stg2.col5), TIME("00:00")) ASC) WHEN "' || param_col_9 || '" = "AMOUNT" AND "' || param_col_10 || '" = "DESC" THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stg2.col10 DESC) WHEN "' || param_col_9 || '" = "AMOUNT" AND "' || param_col_10 || '" = "ASC" THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY stg2.col10 ASC) END row_num FROM staging_2 stg2 INNER JOIN (SELECT  DISTINCT VALUE:account::INT account,  VALUE:bankCode::VARCHAR bankCode,  VALUE:currency::VARCHAR currency FROM (SELECT  parse_json('' || param_json_info_1 || '') as src) src, lateral flatten(input => src) ) cts ON stg2.col13 = cts.account AND stg2.col14 = cts.bankCode AND stg2.col15 = cts.currency WHERE 1 = 1 and iff('' || param_json_info_2 || '' is not null, stg2.col16 in ( select VALUE:transactionType::INT from (  select parse_json('' || param_json_info_2 || '') as src ) src, lateral flatten(input => src) where value is not null ) , true) and iff('' || param_json_info_3 || '' is not null, stg2.col17 in ( select VALUE:storeCode::VARCHAR from ( select parse_json('' || param_json_info_3 || '') as src ) src, lateral flatten(input => src) where value is not null) , true) and stg2.col18 in ( select VALUE:paymentMethod::VARCHAR from ( select parse_json('' || param_json_info_4 || '') as src ) src, lateral flatten(input => src) where value is not null) QUALIFY row_num BETWEEN ' || param_col_11 || '::NUMBER(38,0) + 1 AND ' || param_col_11 || '::NUMBER(38,0) + ' || param_col_12 || '::NUMBER(38,0)) SELECT  col1 column1, col2 column2, col3 column3, col4 column4, col5 column5, col6 column6, col7 column7, col8 column8, col9 column9, col10 column10, col11 column11, col12 column12 FROM last_filter';
    res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
     return 'Sucess';
    exception
    when other then
    err := sqlerrm;
     RETURN (query);
END;
$$;



i add the exception to the actual script, change the return data type to varchar(2000) and leave it like this: res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
return 'Sucess';
exception
when other then
err := sqlerrm;
RETURN (:err); But gives me the same error: SQL compilation error: parse error line 1 at position 11,021 near ''. syntax error line 1 at position 10,191 unexpected 'AS'.

Hi , I have attached the screen print where the query is null, looks like some of the variables are null which is making the whole script null.
